# Prove the following: If $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid \gcd(a, b)c$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Prove the following: If $a \mid bc$, then $a  \mid \gcd(a, b)c$.

I tried to set $\gcd(a, b)$ to $b$ and used the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to prove that it is divisible by $a$, but I can't prove that $a \mid bc$, if and only if $a\mid b$ and $a\mid c$. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Assuming $a\,|\,bc$, consider the cases. We know either $a \, | \, b$ or $a \,|\, c$. If $a \,|\, c$, the proof is trivial, so assume otherwise. I'll let you tinker with the GCD, and return if you're still struggling.

Comment: the above is incorrect.

Comment: let $b=2, c=3, a=6$

Answer (score 5):

The first argument we give uses the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.
In a remark at the end, we do it another way.

Let $p$ be a prime that divides $a$, and let $p^r$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $a$. Let $p^s$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $b$, and let $p^t$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $c$.

Because $a$ divides $bc$, we have $r\le s+t$.

(i) Suppose that $s\ge r$. Then $p^r$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$, and therefore $p^r$ divides the expression on the right.

(ii) Suppose now that $s\lt r$. Then $p^s$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$. Combined with the $p^t$ that comes from $c$, this shows that the highest power of $p$ that divides the right-hand side is $p^{s+t}$. We are finished, since $r\le s+t$.

**Remark:** We wrote a proof that uses FTA, since that is what you mentioned trying. However, we could let $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $a=da'$, $b=db'$. From $a$ divides $bc$ we get that $a'$ divides $b'c$. Since $a'$ and $b'$ are **relatively prime**, we conclude that $a'$ divides $c$. Now it is easy to show that $a$ divides the right-hand side.

Comment: This is the correct proof, not the other one. Just thought I'd endorse, for whatever it's worth.

Comment: I totally get your explanation, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Neither argument is difficult, but we need some number-theoretic machinery. Unique Factorization will do it, or Euclid's Lemma (if $x$ and $y$ are relatively prime, and $x$ divides $yz$, then $x$ divides $z$. Or else we can use Bezout's Theorem (the gcd of $a$ and $b$ is a linear combination of $a$ and $b$) as in noot's solution.

Answer (score 1):

If $a\mid c$ then you are done

If $a\mid b$ then $b=ak$ for some $k$, therefore $a\mid gcd(a,ak)$. Then it is easy to finish the excercise.

Comment: That second line is not correct.

Comment: @Orangutango corrected

Comment: Yes indeed, this is probably the simplest way to see it. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

$gcd(a,b)=ma+nb$

so we need to prove $a|mac+nbc$

$ac$ and $bc$ both divide a.
So their linear combination also divides $a$.

Comment: This approach works nicely,

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\ a\mid ac,bc\,\Rightarrow\,a\mid(ac,bc)=(a,b)c\,$ by the [gcd Distributive Law.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/705874/242)