# Prove that $a\mid c$; given that $a\mid bc$ and $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Please help answer the number theory problem. The proof I came across goes like this:

Let $d = \gcd(a,b)$ then $d = ma + nb$.

$ma + nb = 1$.

then

$mac + nbc = c$.

$a\mid mac$, $a\mid nbc$, therefore $a\mid c$.

Not sure how last step unfolded. Thanks.

(This is my personal question I have not posted it anywhere else, and  the context of my question is my own)

Comment: Which part of the last step are you stuck on? Do you agree that $a|mac$ and that $a| nbc$?

Comment: $mac+nbc = a(mc+n(\color{#c00}{bc/a}))$ and $\color{#c00}{bc/a}$ is an integer by hypothesis. Generally if $\,a\mid x,y $ then $\,a\mid nx+my\,$ for any integers $m,n.\,$ In paricular, the sum of two multiples of $a$ is also a multiple of $a\ \ $

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove the following: If $a \mid bc$, then $a \mid \gcd(a, b)c$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/434164/prove-the-following-if-a-mid-bc-then-a-mid-gcda-bc)

Comment: It's not a duplicate :) they both are different content :)

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, this was my own question.

Comment: @Icycarus I know they are not the same question, but [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/764009/133781) one is a duplicate and it was flagged as duplicate of the question I linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

$am+nb=1\\amc+nbc=c$

Since $a \mid bc$, then $bc = ka$ for some integer $k$. Substituting into your equation, we have that

$amc+ank=c$. Since there are solutions to $am+bn=1$, then there must be solutions to $a(mc+nk)=c$. Hence $a \mid c$

This is also known as Euclid's Lemma.

Another way to think of it is because $mc$ and $nk$ are integers (Since $m$ and $n$ exists), then $mc+nk$ is an integer, which means $\frac ca$ is an integer, which can only mean $a \mid c$.

Comment: very in depth, excellent explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We know $\gcd(a,b)=1\iff au+bv=1$ and $a\mid bc\iff bc=ak$ for some $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $$au+bv=1\implies auc+bvc=c\implies auc+akv=c\implies a(uc+kv)=c\implies a\mid c$$
Note, after the second implication we introduced $bc=ak$.

Comment: Nice ideas for getting a full understanding Much appreciated